# using DistinguishedName in ldap query

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have a requirement where I need to run query like below and fetch 2-3 attributes for all entities satisfying this query. The number of distinguishedName would be around 100 in a single query. As I see in the microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-distinguishedName), that distinguishedName is not indexed, I suspect that this might cause performance issues.

Does anybody know if this would indeed cause performance issues? Apart from the below ldap filter, I would obviously have to use SUBTREE scope.

```
(|(distinguishedName=<DN 1 goes here>)(distinguishedName=<DN 2 goes here>))
```

Edit 1:
I tried this in my test Active Directory which has ~6k entries.

```
Internal event: A client issued a search operation with the following options. 
Starting node:
DC=example,DC=com 
Filter:
 ( |  
(distinguishedName=CN=user-1,CN=large-test,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com)
(distinguishedName=CN=user-2,CN=large-test,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com)
(distinguishedName=CN=user-3,CN=large-test,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com)
(distinguishedName=CN=group1,CN=large-test,CN=Groups,DC=example,DC=com) 
)  
Search scope:
subtree 
Attribute selection:
mail,objectClass 
Server controls:
 
Visited entries:
4 
Returned entries:
4 
Used indexes:
idx_distinguishedName:4:N;idx_distinguishedName:1:N;idx_distinguishedName:1:N;idx_distinguishedName:1:N; 
Pages referenced:
123 
Pages read from disk:
0
```

From the results it looks like it only visited 4 entries that I searched for using some indexes. I checked with schema snap-in tool (just to be sure) and it doesn't show indexes on distinguishedName. Not sure how it's using these indexes though.

Comment: What have you tried?
How often would you run this query?
How are you performing the query? (Code? application? JNDI?)

Comment: I would be fetching all the groups in the active directory and their members. I would also need to fetch member emails. Since during fetching the group list, it only returns member dn and not the email, I would need to fetch emails corresponding to those DNs separately. Since the number of members could be large, this query would be run quite often. We would be running this query via our java app using some ldap library (unboundid).

Comment: The `distinguishedName` attribute doesn't have the index search flag set _because it's not a real attribute_. This sounds a lot like an imagined problem to be honest. If you're really worried: try implementing your query logic in your application, then [test it against a DC with diagnostic logging enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms808539(v=msdn.10)#tracking-expensive-and-inefficient-searches)

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I was looking for something like that which could help me diagnose if the query is efficient or not. I'll try this out.

Comment: Tried running the sample request on test active directory and updated the results above.

Comment: @adarsh003 Notice how it _is_ actually indexed internally (`idx_distinguishedName`) - only 4 entries visited (meaning it didn't have to scan the whole directory) and zero swapping required. Your queries will be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Active Directory stores the group memberships at the entry level, so you could use this to fetch the email attribute.

E.g.
`ldapsearch .... -b SEARCH_BASE "(|(memberOf=GROUP_DN_1)(memberOf=GROUP_DN_2)...)" mail`

Comment: I also was trying this out but the issue here is the same as with distinguishedName as memberOf is also not indexed.

Comment: so you get an 'administrative limit error' back? Would you mind posting the error?

Comment: I haven't tried this approach yet but please see my above update with distinguishedName attribute.